Confusion with the sum of open-loop gain and feedback attenuation
Regarding the following statement taken from here:

Looking at amplitude response on the log plot, circuit instability
occurs when the sum of open-loop gain and feedback attenuation is
greater than unity.

But isn't an open-loop gain is always  too big like one million and feedback attenuation is too small like 0.00001. Isn't than the sum of these always a huge number bigger than one? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

decibels sum < 0dB

Actually the product of the forward gain with the reverse gain that must be less than 1.
Under normal operation, the product is negative so will always be less than unity regardless of magnitude

So is the statement "the sum of open-loop gain and feedback attenuation" wrong? Should it be "the product of open-loop gain and feedback attenuation"?

Yes. It is wrong. Alternatively. The decibel sum must be less than 0dB
